# How can I make a tag work for both input and output

Tags: javascript, html

How to design a container that can do both input and output. I am designing a currency converter, I want a box where users can input data and output calculated currency.

I have tried the code with switching to dividers instead of input tag but it didn't work. So at this point I have made two input boxes and the function simply, takes an input and tries to provide an input into another box. But it doesn't work.

```css
input {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 120px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  Country1:<input type="text" id="in"><br> Country2:
  <input type="text" id="inver"><br>
  <button onclick="Go()">
      Click me
  </button>
  <p id="Country1">
  </p>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Go() {
      var text = document.getElementById("in").value;
      document.getElementById("inver").innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result should show the country 2 input value as the same as country 1.

Comment: Are you using any framework in your app? (Vue, React, Angular, other?) 
Seems like you need to use a `two way data binding` approach.

Comment: set `document.getElementById("inver").value = document.getElementById("in").value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this textfield approach -

```
<input id="inver" type="text">
```

Then in javascript you can take input like this -

```
var inver = document.getElementById('inver')
var inp = inver.value
```

Then in javascript you can output like this -

```
inver.value = "output"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` not innerHTML ,`input types` have value

```js
function Go() {
  var text = document.getElementById("in").value;
  document.getElementById("inver").value = text; // use value
}
```

```css
input {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 120px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Country1:<input type="text" id="in"><br> Country2:
  <input type="text" id="inver"><br>
  <button onclick="Go()">
Click me
</button>
  <p id="Country1">

  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Faster to find a dupe, no?

Comment: Well ,yes its faster to find a dupe but he is a new user ,so thought of answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Because they are both input boxes, you need to change the value, not the innerHTML

```
function Go() {
  var text = document.getElementById("in").value;

  // change this code
  document.getElementById("inver").value = text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To set value to second input use

```
inver.value = text;
```

```css
input {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 120px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    Country1:<input type="text" id="in"><br>
    Country2:<input type="text" id="inver"><br>
    <button onclick="Go()">
Click me
</button>
    <p id="Country1">

    </p>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function Go() {
        var text = document.getElementById("in").value;
        inver.value = text;
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you confusing a noob by not bothering to use getElementById on the second field? I know modern browsers allow this, but it is not intuitive nor consistent. Anyway this is a dupe that is easily found